# implement static,private members using prototypal pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, static, prototype-programming

this is prototypal model in javascript. 
unlike use constructor function with new keyword in this pattern we are using
existing object to create a new object as shown below

```
var answerprototype = {

    name:'ss',
    get:function fn1()
    {
        return "--";

    }
}

var lifeanswer = Object.create(answerprototype);
```

---

this is how implement private ,public members in javascript using classical pattern

```
function Restaurant()
{
    //private varible
    var myPrivateVar = 'aaa';

    //public variable
    this.myPublicVar = 'bbbb'   

    //private method
    // Only visible inside Restaurant()
    var private_stuff = function()   
    {
        return "private metho";
    }

    //public method
    // use_restroom is visible to all
    this.use_restroom = function()   
    {
        return "public method"
    }

}

//create object
var r1 = new Restaurant();

r1.myPrivateVar //return undefined
r1.myPublicVar  //return "bbbb"
r1.private_stuff() //error
r1.use_restroom() //return "public method"
```

---

this is how implement static members in javascript using classical pattern

```
function Shape(shapeName)
{
   //instance field
   this.ShapeName = shapeName;

   //static field
   Shape.Count = ++Shape.Count;

   //static method
   Shape.ShowCount = function()
   {
    return Shape.Count; 
   }

}

var shape1 = new Shape("circle");
var shape1 = new Shape("rectangle");
var shape1 = new Shape("Triangle");


Shape.ShowCount();    //return 3
```

---

i want to implement static members and private ,public members in javascript using prototypal pattern(not using new keyword with constructor function)
how to do it

Answer (score 0):

In *JavaScript, private* doesn't mean what you think it means. You have to create a closure which is where you trap your *"private"* values.

Using a function is the traditional way to create a closure

```
function makeProto(chainTo) {
    const secret = 'foo';
    return Object.assign(Object.create(chainTo || null), {
        get hello() {return secret;}
    });
}

let fizz = makeProto();
fizz.hello; // "foo"
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(fizz, 'hello'); // true
```

With ES6, you can use the block-scoped `let` or `const` in combination with the function scoped `var` to achieve something similar

```
;{
    let foo = 'bar';
    var obj = {
        get baz() {return foo;}
    };
}
obj.baz; // "bar"
foo; // ReferenceError
```

---

Please remember that as soon as you inherit from one of these objects, all descendant objects will **share** the same references to these values, not create new ones

---

I wrote `;{ /* ... */ }` so if you try the code in your console it doesn't attempt to interpret this pattern as an *Object literal*, but instead a *code block*. In production the initial `;` is not necessary.